# One Laptop, Two Projectors (same image)

Tags: untagged

Is it possible to connect one laptop (VGA) to two projectors (one has VGA, other has VGA and USB) and have them both project the same image? Are there adapters or something for this (wireless?) or some kind of product that will make this easy?

Want to be able to do this in a very large conference room.

Comment: Need more details, we talking HDMI,VGA,DVI?

Comment: Sorry, that'd be VGA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make and model of projector?  Depending on this, you have a few options.

- Some projectors have a VGA OUT for this so you can chain projectors.  You can go from the computer to projector 1's VGA in, then from projector 1's VGA out to projector 2's VGA in.
- Some projectors have a software package that you can install and broadcast to multiple projectors over the LAN.
- A [VGA multiplier](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10104) will take one VGA input and provide multiple VGA outputs.

Comment: We have two similar (but slightly different) projectors. Casio XJ-S57 and XJ-S58. Not too sure on the specifics of this, but if we used a multiplier, could we use REALLY long (50+ft) VGA cables?

Comment: Yes, but check with the manufacturer for their recommendations.  I've used high quality 100FT VGA cables without issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [VGA splitter cable](http://eu.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/VGA-Cables/1-ft-VGA-to-2x-VGA-Video-Splitter-Cable%E2%80%93Male-to-Female~VGASPL1VV).

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of this compared to a VGA multiplier?

Comment: This cable is in fact a tiny VGA multiplier.

Comment: Non-powered though. I assume a powered multiplier would be much more friendly with long distances?

Comment: As I quote MikeyB: You'll notice the colours are dimmer on the unpowered splitter.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [USB to VGA adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J4MT5Q) should help. And depending on your projector type, you might be able to connect the other projector to the first one. (If it has that option.)

Comment: I made some basic edits to your answer.  While the content itself wasn't terrible, formatting goes a LONG way on this site.